# how to replace first character in the second column of pipe delimited file using awk and sed command

Tags: awk, sed

Example :
in the below example, I need to replace first occurence of '1' in second column to '2'

```
Col1|col2
1001|1003
1002|1004
1003|1005
```

My output should be like:

```
Col1|col2
1001|2003
1002|2004
1003|2005
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Do you need to replace the first character (as stated in your subject) or the first occurrence of `1` (as stated in your text)? If the first character can sometimes be other than 1 then, obviously, include that case in your sample input/output. [edit] your question to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/|1/|2/' file
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** alternative (to replace *first* occurrence of `1` in second column to `2`):

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{ sub("1","2",$2) }1' OFS='|' file
```

The output:

```
Col1|col2
1001|2003
1002|2004
1003|2005
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\| '{sub(/1/,"2",$2)}1' OFS=\| file

Col1|col2
1001|2003
1002|2004
1003|2005
```